# iPhone 5 hanged and now cannot be entered

Tags: iphone, performance

Was using Chrome and WhatsApp on my iPhone 5 when the two apps hanged. Since I was unable to activate multitasking, such as to restart those apps, I tried to lock the phone. However, upon locking my phone, I was unable to unlock the phone. The phone is still switched on, since I can still activate Siri, but the lock screen is pitch black, so I am unable to access my passcode lock screen to unlock the phone. Essentially, my phone is switched on, but is effectively a brick. I am unable to do a hard reset on my phone, since my switch does not work (as a result of being used too often, the wire in the switch has come out of place and renders the switch obsolete).

I connected my phone to my MacBook Air so as to backup and then restore the phone, but the backup has failed a few times, so I cannot restore the phone yet. Does anybody know how I can troubleshoot my phone to get it working properly again?

Comment: Have you tried draining the battery to 0% (aka leaving it for a _long_ time) then booting it up?

Comment: You are unable to hold down the power and home buttons at the same time?

Comment: @Brick I will try that approach....

Comment: @JohnRamos My power button isn't functioning...I never got down to fixing it as I could work around it, until now

Comment: @ILTJ Brick's idea seems good. You could try draining your battery faster by having Siri play music or make a phone call (that you could leave running).

Comment: I wonder if you could control the phone using a Bluetooth keyboard if the screen does not work. Provided you have a Bluetooth keyboard that is paired with your phone, you could try enabling VoiceOver by triple-tapping the home button. Then the left and right arrow keys on the keyboard will let you select different elements of the screen, pressing the up and down arrow at the same time to tap that selected item. (And you may need to press the left and right arrow to toggle quick-nav so it is on for keyboard arrows to work as controllers.)

Comment: @Brick Your approach worked perfectly. Went to fix the power switch anyway. Thanks all!

Comment: @ILTJ Glad we all helped.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Drain your phone battery to 0% by leaving it on its own (or as suggested, play music using Siri or make a phone call that you can leave running, if that's possible).

Comment: What if Siri doesn't work?

Comment: You could leave your phone to run, but that would take longer.